# Is a function discrete or continuous w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I just read a paper where it said that

> However, if the base measure $G_0$ is **absolutely continuous with respect
>   to Lebesgue measure**, parameters will not be shared between groups.
>   Only in the case where the base measure G0 is discrete will there be a
>   strictly positive probability of the group specific distributions
>   having overlapping support (i.e. sharing parameters between groups.)

What does the part in bold mean? I cannot seem to find a answer on Google that I understand, nor any useful papers.

My understanding is that the Lebesgue measure can tell us if a function is discrete or continuous? The wiki is not very helpful either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important characterizations of this notion. In both, I use $\lambda$ to refer to the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ to refer to some other measure.

1. $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure if for all Lebesgue measurable sets $A$ with $\lambda(A)=0$, $\mu(A)=0$.
2. $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ if there exists a Lebesgue measurable function $f$ such that $\mu(A) = \int_A f d \lambda$ for all Lebesgue measurable sets $A$.

It is not hard to see that 2 implies 1. The statement "1 implies 2" is an instance of the *Radon-Nikodym theorem*. Accordingly, in analysis the function $f$ in the second characterization is referred to as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$, and is sometimes denoted by $\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}$.

A different place that you may have encountered this notion under a different name is in probability theory. The probability distribution of a (one-dimensional) continuous random variable is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. In this context the function $f$ in my second characterization is called the density of the random variable.

Comment: Ahhhh I see; yes this is very firmly rooted in probability theory, from whence I got the quote from. Very good explanation thanks.

Comment: The Poisson probability distribution [a discrete distribution] - could it be said then to be discontinuous according to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Astrid It is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, if that is what you mean.